# why are those errors appearing in my console?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I've just made a setup for C# in vs code, and I wanted to run a hello world app but those errors appear :

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018: Échec inattendu
 de la tâche "CreateAppHost". [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018: System.Aggregat
eException: One or more errors occurred. (Access to the path 'C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\obj\Debug\net6.0\apphost.exe' i 
s denied.) (Access to the path 'C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\obj\Debug\net6.0\apphost.exe' is denied.) [C:\Users\insaf\One 
Drive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:  ---> System.Un 
authorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\obj\Debug\net6.0\apphost.exe' is denied. [C:\U 
sers\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft 
.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions option 
s) [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft 
.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int 
64 preallocationSize) [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO 
.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 p 
reallocationSize) [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO 
.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions option 
s, Int64 preallocationSize) [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO 
.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategy(FileStream fileStream, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, 
 Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize) [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO 
.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft 
.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<CreateAppHost>b__2() [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]  
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft 
.NET.HostModel.RetryUtil.RetryOnIOError(Action func) [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft 
.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.CreateAppHost(String appHostSourceFilePath, String appHostDestinationFilePath, String appBinaryFi 
lePath, Boolean windowsGraphicalUserInterface, String assemblyToCopyResorcesFrom, Boolean enableMacOSCodeSign) [C:\Users\insaf\OneD 
rive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    --- End of i 
nner exception stack trace --- [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft 
.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.CreateAppHost(String appHostSourceFilePath, String appHostDestinationFilePath, String appBinaryFi 
lePath, Boolean windowsGraphicalUserInterface, String assemblyToCopyResorcesFrom, Boolean enableMacOSCodeSign) [C:\Users\insaf\OneD 
rive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft 
.NET.Build.Tasks.CreateAppHost.ExecuteCore() [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft 
.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft 
.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp 
.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft 
.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, Tas 
kHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]        
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:  ---> (Inner Ex 
ception #1) System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\obj\Debug\net6.0\apphost. 
exe' is denied. [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO 
.FileSystem.DeleteFile(String fullPath) [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO 
.File.Delete(String path) [C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft 
.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.CreateAppHost(String appHostSourceFilePath, String appHostDestinationFilePath, String appBinaryFi 
lePath, Boolean windowsGraphicalUserInterface, String assemblyToCopyResorcesFrom, Boolean enableMacOSCodeSign)<--- [C:\Users\insaf\ 
OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(554,5): error MSB4018:  [C:\Users\insa 
f\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\csharp.csproj]
```

Comment: Look at `(Access to the path 'C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\obj\Debug\net6.0\apphost.exe' is denied.) `  That generally indicateds that either you are running the program already and trying to compile it (the EXE is locked because it is running) or because you don't have access to the folder (which seems unlikely)

Comment: What's a `setup for C#` and how did you make yours?

Comment: Compiling code straight onto OneDrive sounds like a bad idea. Put your project elsewhere. If you need to backup your code, use a version control system like Git.

Answer (score 0):

You see the second line says this

```
 Access to the path 'C:\Users\insaf\OneDrive\Bureau\csharp\obj\Debug\net6.0\apphost.exe' is denied.)
```

Looks like a clue to me -- did you check this directory to see if it is available?

Comment: I checked but it's unavailable

Comment: I checked but it's unavailable, there's no such file named apphost.exe

Comment: now you know the root cause

Comment: what can you suggest as a solution ?

Comment: Something is installed wrong if a  file is missing.   I would go back and make sure I installed everything I needed or start over and re-install the needed components and make sure nothing gave an error I did not see the first time.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a problem caused by onedrive file permissions or synchronization. Exit onedrive after all onedrive synchronization is completed, delete the obj directory in the project, and then use VS Code to perform operations such as modification,compilation,etc.